# Spring AMQP reconnection issue with rabbitmq cluster due to queue checking retry limit

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a rabbitmq cluster with 3 nodes. One node has a durable and non-mirrored classic queue named `test-queue`.

I have a spring boot app using spring-AMQP default connection factory `new CachingConnectionFactory()` to firstly ensure the queue exists and then subscribe its messages. Everything works fine

Then I started a rolling update to the rabbitmq cluster, where node was being restarted one by one.

I observed following during this process from the log:

Upon start I saw below output

```
Received shutdown signal for consumer tag=amq.ctag-pzPHM_GEd5e-J5Y_L2W7_g com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0)
...
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory[m][] - Attempting to connect to: xxx:5672
...
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory[m][] - Created new connection: xxx#66971f6b:58/SimpleConnection@4315e774
```

Which shows that the app received shutdown signal and successfully reconnected. At this point, it looks like the node that has the queue was shut down, but the app was able to establish a new connection because there are other nodes

Later I saw more shut down signal which indicates the other node started to shutdown

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer[m][] - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; protocol method: #method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced
```

At the same time I noticed below logs, which indicate that although connected, spring amqp can't find the queue. I guess it is because the node has the queue was down. Spring amqp might be checking other nodes. It thought the queue does not exist so it started to recreate the queue. Also note that there was a retry limit which is `3`

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer[m][] - Failed to declare queue: test-queuey
Queue declaration failed; retries left=3 org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[test-queue]
...
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - queue 'test-queue' in vhost '/' process is stopped by supervisor, class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

At the end, retry exhausted. I noticed the followings. Looks like spring amqp give up, and started to close everything. The end state was that, no consumer registered to the queue. Spring app was still running but not be able to get messages. It no longer retry like how the disconnection is handled. The resolution was to reboot the app.

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer[m][] - Cancelling Consumer@7f74d6dd: tags=[[]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@xxx:5672/,26), conn: Proxy@65ef722a Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4315e774 [delegate=amqp://guest@xxx:5672/, localPort= 37208], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer[m][] - Closing Rabbit Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@xxx:5672/,26), conn: Proxy@65ef722a Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@4315e774 [delegate=amqp://guest@xxx:5672/, localPort= 37208]
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory[m][] - Closing cached Channel: AMQChannel
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer[m][] - Stopping container from aborted consumer
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer[m][] - Shutting down Rabbit listener container
```

I get spring amqp come with a retry on disconnection logic which keeps reconnecting indefinitely. But for such case, how can I make it so that spring wait until cluster restart is completed then start reconnecting? or is there a way to disable the retry limit on the queue checking so that it will keep checking the queue until cluster restart is completed instead of giving up early? Would changing queue to mirrored queue or Quorum queue resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#declarationRetries

> The number of retry attempts when passive queue declaration fails. Passive queue declaration occurs when the consumer starts or, when consuming from multiple queues, when not all queues were available during initialization. When none of the configured queues can be passively declared (for any reason) after the retries are exhausted, the container behavior is controlled by the 'missingQueuesFatal` property, described earlier.

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#failedDeclarationRetryInterval

> The interval between passive queue declaration retry attempts. Passive queue declaration occurs when the consumer starts or, when consuming from multiple queues, when not all queues were available during initialization.

You can increase one or both of these from their defaults (3 and 5000 respectively).

Comment: Thanks! If I change it to infinite say 5000. When the node holds the queue come back up while the app is trying to recreate the queue, will it detect the queue and stop the retry process?

Comment: It doesn't "create" the queue; it is doing a passive declaration to check if the queue is present; it will keep retrying until it succeeds or the `declarationRetries` is exceeded. Once it succeeds it will consume again.